# How to find all places where variable is used in JMeter scenario?

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I use JMeter to record HTTP scenario and do load testing. Now I need to correlate some values using Regular Expression Extractor, for example ${secure_id}, but I don't know how to find all requests where this variable is used. I can substitute this step by step, but it is necessary for me to do it automatically in all places where it is used. Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you seen "Search" option in JMeter's main menu? It's available since JMeter 2.9 if not earlier

   [image: JMeter Search]
2. As @Boyan suggests JMeter scripts are XML files so you can use your favourite text editor for bulk replacing hardcoded recorded value with the variable
3. You can use a 3rd-party recorder which has SmartJMX mode. The main feature is automatic correlation of any detected entities. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for details.

Comment: Thanks for all ways you are suggested. This is what you need

Answer (score 2):

You could open your TestPlan.jmx file with text editor notepad++ for example and find+replace all occurrences of ${secure_id} here is an example [image]

Comment: Thanks, I do now this way, but I want to do it using JMeter only.